# Медленная загрузка WinXP SP3

Tags: windows, explorer

Такой вопрос. У меня система чересчур медленно грузится. Пробовал просмотреть все журналы, все ошибки -- ничего такого, что могло бы навести на след. Пробовал запустить систему в диагностическом режиме -- грузится гораздо быстрее, но без служб, как без ушей... В сети прочитал про BootVis, попробовал -- никак. Она просто при загрузке системы выдаёт "Инструкция такая-то обратилась к памяти по адресу такому-то". И всё. Облазил весь Инет, но ничего путного так и не нашел. Что делать? На случай: ОЗУ 4ГБ, ЦП 1,8ГГц.

UPDATE

Хочу заметить: при полном отключении всех служб посредством msconfig система грузится более-менее нормально. Но перебирать все службы -- дело хлопотное. Одну из тормозящих служб я нашел: Обозреватель компьютеров. Но это не предел. Что-то ещё сильно тормозит загрузку. Как узнать, что?

Comment: Сразу после установки медленно грузилась или через какое-то время после?

Comment: Через пару месяцев после установки. Сразу: проблем с реестром вроде нет, я его регулярно чищу, вирусов ни один антивирус не нашел. А вот после чего именно так стало тормозить -- не помню;)...

Comment: У товарища была подобная проблема. Долго висит заставка "Приветствие пользователя". Так и не удалось победить ее. Причем, если выдернуть кабель - то окно быстро пропадает и пользователь авторизуется на машине. Если сетевой кабель будет подключен к компьютеру, то окно приветствия несколько минут бывает висит. В общем наши исследования остановились на том, что долго получается сетевой адрес. Может это вас натолкнет на мысль. Мы уже сдались с этой проблемой. (Может антивирь/сетевой экран дурит?)

Answer (score 2):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопос - службы. 
Панель управления -> администрирование и методом тыка исключайте тяжеловесные службы.

Comment: Используя Auslogics Service Manager, который показывает вес службы, я исключал их всех по очереди и вместе. Не помогает. Кроме того, у меня 124 службы, и перебрать их всех просто нереально...

Comment: Значит проблемма при загрузке драйверов. возможно их слишком много. Но это мало вероятно. А сама система после загрузки работает производительно? и сколько потребляет памяти ОС. хотя 4 гб должно с лихвой хватить.

Comment: Программа Autoruns говорит, что у меня 185 драйверов=)... Пик выделения памяти -- 1,3 ГБ. Насчет дров у меня сомнения: возможно, и впрямь много. Но определить, что лишнее, я не могу.

Answer (score 1):

99% Проблема появляется с установкой какого нибудь мусорного софта, который скорее всего имеет аналоги. Если компьютер не работает в сети (корпоративной) попробуйте отключить лишние службы типа "справка и поддержка", "удаленный реестр". Лучше всего сделать их запускаемыми вручную. Проверьте винчестер на дохлые сектора, вы его давно купили? Проверьте линии +5 +12 БП, если они сильно отклоняются, лучше сменить БП, особенно если он старый. Проверьте планки памяти (вроде у мелкософтов была тула для проверки), посмотрите не окислились ли на ней контакты, если это так - протрите ластиком. Проверьте на окисление также все платы расширения. Попробуйте переустановить систему, устанавливайте только в первый раздел диска. Ставьте размер файла подкачки 1,5 размера ОЗУ. Поставьте все обновления системы.

Судя по тому что у вас 4ГБ ОЗУ у вас наверняка 64 бита система и наверняка английская. Я бы рекомендовал перейти на Win7 ту что x64.

Comment: Итак, службы наподобие удаленного реестра или удаленного помощника у меня отключены, винт проверял на ошибки -- ошибок нет. БП новый. Память совсем новая, ей и года нет, да и MemoryTest ошибок на ней не нашел. Насчёт переустановки я говорил, что это в самую последнюю очередь, тем более, что мой винт нельзя разметить так, чтоб на новом разделе было более 2 ГБ. Файл подкачки -- 3500 МБ. Обновления регулярно проверяются и устанавливаются. Система -- MS Windows SP3 RUS, и 86x.

Comment: Я могу сказать что это очень странно, проверяйте софт.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можно попробовать произвести дефрагментацию харда. сразу после неё, кстати, бывает полезно загрузится в режиме "восстановление службы каталогов"(точно название не помню, но как-то так).

Comment: Да, забыл сказать, процесс это не быстрый, в зависимости от размеров, забитости и быстродействия харада может длится от нескольких часов до суток.

Comment: Дефрагментировался периодично, и разными программами. Не спасает. Проводил дефрагментацию и чистку реестра и всех дисков. Безрезультатно.

Comment: а "восстановление службы каталогов" не пробовали? редко конечно помогает, но пару раз было замечено.

Comment: Пробовал. Через пару секунд после выбора опции "Восстановление служб каталогов" комп перезагружается. Пробовал после выбора этой опции сразу нажать F8->"отключить автоматическую перезагрузку" -- появляется BSOD, причём причина перезагрузки не указана. Потом, после этого, если я пробую загрузиться -- комп уже перегружается после выбора оси и в обычном режиме, так что спасает от этого только одно -- "Загрузка последней удачной конфигурации.

Answer (score 0):

Фигасе до чего доехали))) дефрагментация :) эта фикня уже даавно помогает не ускорить а замедлить загрузку(на семёрочке тойже заметил). Кароч. ставь систему, дрова, дефрагментируйся какойнить серьёзной прогой, потом ток ставь все необходимые проги...

Comment: Переставить думаю, но на харде много важной инфы, всех флешек не хватит, чтоб забэкапить. Но, думаю, если РЕАЛЬНО выхода нет -- придётся переустанавливать... И насчёт серьёзных программ: я дефрагментировался SmartDefrag, Advanced System Care, Piriform Defraggler и Auslogics Дефрагментатор. Быстрее не стало.

Comment: Так ясное дело.. фрагментация это вообще фигня и в каких-то редких случаях она сказывается, если вы читаете фрагментированные данные сутки напролёт, то может пару процентов набежит разницы от дефрагментации

Comment: Не скажите. После тщательной дефрагментации комп стал работать заметно быстрее. Но не грузиться...

Answer (score 0):

Пуск > Выполнить > msconfig > enter
Вот там выбираем "службы", поставив галочку "не показывать службы Мелкомягких", смотрим что именно в автозагрузке торчит. Чистим приложения типа groovemonitor и прочих ненужных, и наслаждаемся нормальной работой ПК.
Имхо, нужную службу или программу проще подгрузить к моменту использования.

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Отключил все службы, которые остались после отключения Майкрософтовских -- без толку.

Comment: А avz или cureit в безопасном режиме запускали?

Comment: Запускал CureIT! в безопасном режиме.

Answer (score 0):

а может тебя rootkit тормозит?
проверь систему RootkitRevealer-ом (найдешь на www.sysinternals.com)

Comment: Я проверял RootkitBuster от TrendMicroSystems, а также антивирусниками: NOD32, DrWeb, SpyBot, Malwarebytes AntiMalware, Iobit MalwareFighter, Iobit Security 360, SuperAntiMalware и ClamAntiVirus. Они ничего не обнаружили. Когда я пускаю RootkitRevealer, комп просто виснет на некотором проценте сканирования. Причём ни ЦП, ни ОЗУ не перегружаются. Просто зависает на ровном месте.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ccleaner скачать не пробовал?
2. Исправление ошибок
3. Windows нормальный возьми, а то весь с багами
4. Комп слабый, быть может
5. Напиши свою конфигурацию компа. ЖДУ!!!

Comment: 1)CCleaner использую регулярно
2)Проверял на ошибки программами Auslogics, NortonWinDoctor2009, тем же самим AdvancedSystemCarePro и Dachshud Hare\AntiCrach. Если ошибки и находит, то не те, то есть комп от чистки не быстрее.
3)Windows я буду переустанавливать в самую последнюю очередь, если ничего другого не останется.
4 и 5) Комп нормальный: ОЗУ 4ГБ, ЦП AMD Athlon 3000+ 1,8ГГц, HDD 70ГБ, графика nVidia GeForce 6100 nForce 430, видеопамять 512 МБ, для Интернет использую D-Link DWA-525 Wireless(...), хотя есть встроенная сетевуха nNidia Networking Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто—Чистая загрузка ОС, нет проблем—удалите из Автозагрузки всё ненужное, что можно запустить позже руками, кроме антивируса. Из служб оставьте только антивирус и жизненно-важное. Вот и все чудеса.
И, да. Не пользуйтесь разного рода "чистильщиками и оптимизаторами". У многих может быть положительный опыт с ними, но это временно. Поверьте моему 2-ух—летнему опыту работы в саппорте Microsoft.

Comment: Программы автозапуска грузятся после загрузки winlogon. У меня тормоз начинается ещё перед запуском explorer. В подробном выводе сообщений о загрузке я некоторое время вижу "Восстановление сетевых подключений", затем "Запуск wgalogon.dll" (что это такое -- я не знаю). И только потом появляется картинка рабочего стола, и после минутного ожидания -- собственно ярлыки и Панель Задач. Хотя Ваш совет попробую реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

"обозреватель компьютеров" - сетевая служба, так что можно попробовать обновить драйвера сетевой платы.

если не используете общий доступ то попытайтесь отключить ещё службу "Сервер"

я, кстати, не въехал, у вас когда тормозо проявляются? если во время загрузки профиля пользователя, то тогда можно попробовать создать новго пользователя и посмотреть быстрее или нет. =)

Comment: Некроответы к некровопросам?